# Slider Button Widget(like in Iphone lock Screen)

Tags: android, button, android-activity, slider, listener

i need to create an activity similar to lock screen in iphone(button slider)in android,so that when a user enters username/pswd and slides the button it should take to the next screen...did anyone worked on a scenario like this or if not any idea how this can be done?

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

You probably will have to write your own view. check the following links out from developer.android.com

http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html